calculating the color of a galaxy and making the k correction
I want to know if this is correct:
I have in my dataset: $u_{mag}, u_{mag_{err}}, r_{mag}, r_{mag_{err}}$
Calculating the $u_{r_{color}}$:
$u_{r_{color}} = u_{mag} - r_{mag}$
$u_{r_{color_{err}}} = u_{mag_{err}} - r_{mag_{err}}$
once I have the k-correction value for this color, i apply:
$u_{r_{color_{corr}}} = (u_{mag} - k_{cor_{u}}) - (r_{mag} - k_{cor_r})$
is that right?

i reformatted the thing, I believe this is what you referred to, please format it next time!
